# Busca via ajax durante digitação em input text ( autocomplete )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, algoritmo-de-busca

Fiz uma busca utilizando `ajax` que ao clicar em um botão dispara uma requisição com o termo procurado e retorna com dados que preenchem um `combobox html` (`select`). Até aí tudo bem. No entanto, achei interessante mudar esse comportamento de clicar no botão para buscar, para, ao invés disso, ser verificado no `onkeyup()` durante a digitação.

Acontece que sinto que haverá uma carga extra sobre o servidor e gostaria de saber se vocês sugerem alguma prática que não onere tanto. Alguma técnica diferente fazendo alguma espécie de `cache` que eu desconheço, ou ao invés de fazer busca a cada tecla digitada levantada, verificar após um número mínimo x de teclas ser digitado (etc).

**Outra questão:** Mas e se eu limitar a busca a mais de 3 caracteres e depois existir alguma ocorrência de exatos 3 caracteres?

Só **não** queria:

1. Que o usuário sempre tivesse que clicar pra buscar e;
2. Fazer requisições demais desnecessárias.

Ideias?

Segue código abaixo com um exemplo resumido do que estou tentando fazer:

**formulario_busca.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> <!-- Css do Bootstrap opcional, só coloquei pra carregar um estilinho básico e mostrar o íconezinho da lupa -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#termo_busca').keyup(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url:  'busca_ajax.php',
              data: {
                  nome: $("#termo_busca").val()
              },
              success: function(data) 
              {
                $('#listafornecedores').html(data);
              }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
    <style>
        body { font-size:14pt; padding:5%; }
        #listafornecedores { width:500px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    Nome fornecedor: <input type="text" id="termo_busca" name="termo_busca">
    <button id="btn_busca">
        Procurar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
    </button>

    <br><br>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <b>Fornecedores encontrados com o termo pesquisado:</b><br>
    <select id="listafornecedores" onclick="if( $('#listafornecedores').html() == '' ){ alert('Sem resultados carregados.\n Faça uma busca digitando o nome de um fornecedor.');}"></select>

    <br>
    ... outros campos ...
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salvar">
    </form>

</body>
<html>
```

**busca_ajax.php**

```
<?php
/*
    --Tabela fornecedores usada para teste:

    CREATE TABLE `fornecedores` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    ALTER TABLE `fornecedores`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD KEY `idx_fornecedor_nome` (`nome`);

    ALTER TABLE `fornecedores`
      MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

    --Massa de testes: fornecedores disponíveis para busca
    INSERT INTO `fornecedores` (`nome`) VALUES ('Samsung'),('Microsoft'), ('Apple'),('Fornecedor Homônimo RJ'),('Fornecedor Homônimo SP'),('Fornecedor Homônimo MG');

*/


//MySQLi DESENVOLVIMENTO
$db_host="localhost";
$db_port="5432";
$db_name="testdb";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";

$dbcon = mysqli_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_password );
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,$db_name);
mysqli_query($dbcon,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$_POST["nome"]);

// se enviar nome vazio, não carregar nada
if(trim($nome)==''){ die(); }

$query = "SELECT * FROM fornecedores WHERE nome like '$nome%'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);

$options='';

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     $options.='<option value="'.$linha["id"].'">'.$linha["nome"].'</option>';
}

echo $options;  // isto voltará na variável data do ajax
```

Comment: Eu poderia sugerir `JQuery autocomplete`, mas fugiria do escopo da pergunta...

Comment: Recomendo utilizar uma lib para fazer isso, como está que foi sugerida no comentário acima. Com relação a um número menor de requisição, creio que não seja possível, já que um autocompletar tem que responder a qualquer letra fornecida pelo usuário. Se os dados são poucos, você pode fornecer eles na requisição inicial.

Comment: Você também pode adicionar um pequeno delay depois do evento `keyup`: https://api.jquery.com/delay/ . Só tome cuidado e balanceie com a expectativa de tempo de resposta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo do gênero:

```
var cache = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    addKeyupEvent($('#termo_busca'));
}   

function addKeyupEvent(element) {
    element.keyup(function(e) {
        var keyword = $(this).val();
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        if (e.keyCode == 13)
            updateListData(search(keyword, true));
        else
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
                updateListData(search(keyword));
            }, 500));
    });
}

function search(keyword, force) {
    if (!force && keyword.length < 4) 
        return '';

    if(cache.hasOwnProperty(keyword))
        return cache[keyword];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'busca_ajax.php',
        async: false,
        data: {
           nome: keyword
        },
        success: function(data) {
           cache[keyword] = data;
           return data;
        },
        error: function() {
            throw new Error('Error occured');
        }
    });
}

function updateListData(data) {
     $('#listafornecedores').html(data);
}
```

O que código acima faz é realizar uma pesquisa somente 500ms após pressionar a última tecla, armazenando um temporizador na coleção `.data()` do elemento `#termo_busca`. Cada keyup limpa esse temporizador e define um outro tempo de espera de 500ms antes da busca automática.

Caso o utilizador pressione a tecla "enter" (muito comum nas pesquisas), a busca será realizada automaticamente.

Entretanto se o termo já foi pesquisado, então devolvemos a lista em cache.

Separei as responsabilidades, a função `addKeyupEvent` adiciona o evento `keyup` a qualquer elemento desejado, a função `search` recebe a palavra pesquisada e se a busca automática deve ser forçada (no caso do utilizador pressionar o `ENTER`) e a função `updateListData` apenas atualiza a lista de fornecedores.

Uma dica, não utilize o `POST` para fazer pesquisas (entretanto deixei o `POST` no exemplo). O método `POST` basicamente é usado para criar recursos no servidor, que não é o seu caso. O que você pretende é obter (`GET`) um recurso do servidor, que nesse caso é uma lista de fornecedores.

Comment: Atrasar a busca durante a digitação em 0,5 segundo, cancelando a busca se forem digitados mais caracteres durante esse pequeno intervalo de tempo, como vc fez, tb é muito útil. +1 tb.

Answer (score 4):

Se sua questão é peso que várias requisições resultará. Um alternativa é você trazer todos os dados para o select, e ir eliminando-os conforme for sendo digitado. Dessa forma evitaria todas essas requisições:

```js
$('#termo_busca').on('keypress change', function() {
     $("#listafornecedores").val("");
     $('#listafornecedores option').each(function() {
       if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf($('#termo_busca').val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
         $(this).css("display", "none");
       } else {
         $(this).css("display", "block");
       }
     });

   });
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 5%;
}
#listafornecedores {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Nome fornecedor:
<input type="text" id="termo_busca" name="termo_busca">
<button id="btn_busca">
  Procurar <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>
</button>

<br>
<br>

<form action="" method="post">
  <b>Fornecedores encontrados com o termo pesquisado:</b>
  <br>
  <select id="listafornecedores" onclick="if( $('#listafornecedores').html() == '' ){ alert('Sem resultados carregados.\n Faça uma busca digitando o nome de um fornecedor.');}">
    <option id="vazio" value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Samsung</option>
    <option value="2">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="3">Apple</option>
    <option value="4">Fornecedor Homônimo RJ</option>
    <option value="5">Fornecedor Homônimo SP</option>
    <option value="6">Fornecedor Homônimo MG</option>

  </select>

  <br>... outros campos ...
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salvar">
</form>
```

Comment: Para coisas pequenas, como tipos, normalmente eu já trago do banco mesmo.

Comment: Qual é o problema de fazer desta forma como coloquei?

Comment: Problema nenhum. ^_^ Vou testar ainda. Mas já dei +1 pela boa vontade.

Comment: Ah sim. E pode tambem trazer todos "invisiveis" tambem, e não só quando ele vai digitando, como fiz ai . :)

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre acredito que seria melhor já trazer tudo previamente carregado e ir filtrando na tela, do que, ir toda hora no servidor buscando os novos fornecedores. Ficaria mais rápido dessa maneira e evitaria trafego desnecessário para o seu servidor ;)

Comment: Na verdade esse exemplo utilizando "Fornecedores" foi só um exemplo mesmo. Talvez um exemplo ruim pois quando se pensa em fornecedores se pensa num número pequeno, de repente "produtos" seria melhor. Penso que se a busca virá com mais de cem registros já começa a ser válido esse esforço do ajax. Mas sim, há casos e casos. Mas as respostas estão boas, acho q vou precisar pegar um pedaço de cada pra criar um componente genérico que seja bom na maioria dos casos.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre . Vejo assim, quanto mais registro tiver e mais requisições efetuar, mais peso trará. Com um modelo como coloquei, voce efetuará somente uma requisição. E se o problema é que de inicio todos os registros ficaram a mostra, é só deixar todos invisiveis até que o cliente comece a pesquisar. Mas, fazer varias requisições... seria meio desnecessário. Mesmo se voce efetuar a pesquisa depois de digitados 3 caracteres, vai ser grande ainda o numero de requisições

Comment: Vejo assim, num sistema procurando nomes de pessoas:
Isoladamente tem 5 mil registro, após digitar os 4 primeiros caracteres se eu for pegar só os nomes que começam pelo termo e não termos pelo meio, imaginamos que esse número caiu pra uns 100, daí esses 100 são carregados, ao invés dos 5 mil e com seu código adaptado vou limpando durante a digitação da pessoa sem precisar fazer novas requisições, faria nova requisição apenas se aqueles 4 primeiros caracteres digitados mudassem.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandre pensando assim... Acho que é uma boa mesmo kk :)

Answer (score 2):

**formulario_busca.php**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#termo_busca').keyup(function()
    {
        var cep_field = $(this);
        if(cep_field.val() >= 8){ //altere a constante caso esteja usando mascara de campo
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'busca_ajax.php',
                data: {
                    nome: $("#termo_busca").val()
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#listafornecedores').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi em que isso resolve o problema do usuário. Aparentemente ele quer saber um jeito de fazer menos requisições para o servidor.

Comment: Ajuda um pouco se nessa verificação eu usar com uma função de contagem de caracteres.  Mas  . val () retorna o valor do campo e não a quantidade de caracteres usada. Mau humor está certo. Mas obrigado pela boa vontade em ajudar.   Só que essa resposta assim não tenho mesmo como marcar como resposta escolhida. Fica a pergunta em aberto pra quem tiver ideias melhores.

Comment: Não tinha entendido a função daquele IF. Porem, fazer dessa forma compromete muito a usabilidade da tua ferramenta. Pense no seguinte caso, eu quero pesquisar "Mau Humor", ai então digito 'M' e não vem nenhum resultado. Vou supor que não existe essa palavra, em vez de digitar mais letras até completar o número de letras requerido.

Comment: Verdade,  concordo que pode acontecer isso. Se eu terminar usando uma solução assim vou precisar pôr um aviso para a pessoa precisar digitar pelo menos 3 caracteres.

Comment: Eu entendi que o usuária queria diminuir o numero de rquisições restringindo o trigger da busca apenas quando o cep já estivesse completo, este código é bem básico eu particularmente, usaria uma regex para limpar o conteúdo analisado e usaria uma chamada $.post, mas foi apenas um código simples para exemplificar um maneira simples de resolução, maneiras melhores sempre podem ser implementadas.

Comment: No seu lugar eu usaria o plugin typehead do twitter que abstrairia essa camada de busca para você. https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: Parece bom tb Bruno. Grato pelo link.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode restringir as requisições no tempo, usando uma variável de sessão ou cookie.

Antes de fazer uma requisição, você testa a variável pra saber se o tempo já passou. Caso afirmativo, executa a requisição e atualiza a variavel com o novo limite. Senão pula.

Ajustando o intervalo, você consegue um bom tempo de resposta e menor sobrecarga.

Meu javascript tá meio enferrujado, mas vou comentar as ações no código

```
$('#termo_busca').keyup(function()
    {

          // o cookie não existe ou já passou da hora?
          // executa o $.ajax()
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:  'busca_ajax.php',
          data: {
              nome: $("#termo_busca").val()
          },
          success: function(data) 
          {
            $('#listafornecedores').html(data);
          }
        });
         // senão, pula e cria o cookie com o limite de tempo.
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#termo_busca').keyup(function () {
        var termo = $(this).val();
        var fazerAjax = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < listaFornecedores.length; i++) { //Lista de fornecedores do ultimo Ajax
            if (listaFornecedores[i].search(termo) != -1) //Caso o que o usuario esteja digitado tenha ainda tenha na lista do ultimo ajax não realizar o ajax de novo.
                fazerAjax = false;
        }
        if (termo.length >= 3 && fazerAjax) { //Só fazer o ajax caso o termo de busca seja maior e igual a 3 e o texto digitado seja diferente de todos os fornecedores do ultimo ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'busca_ajax.php',
                data: {
                    nome: termo
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#listafornecedores').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Dessa forma você vai realizar um novo Ajax, caso o que o usuário queria seja diferente do que você buscou no último Ajax.

Comment: Essa ideia de verificar o que já tem na lista antes de mandar outra consulta tb é muito boa. Porque se com 4 caracteres já tá trazendo um catatau de resultados, de repente se o 5 seguir os 4 anteriores eu com java-script mesmo já mato os que começarem a fugir do escopo. ainda vou testar o código mas +1 pela ideia.

Comment: Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 2):

O link [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) tem um exemplo prático, pode te ajudar, carregando resultado a partir da terceira ou segunda letra.

ou então carregar todos os dados em json e consultar nesse resultado, sem mais requisições no servidor.. há um [microframework](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/) de 2kb que pode usado pra isso.

Os resultados são carregados em arrays.

```
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");

    // Show label but insert value into the input:
new Awesomplete(input, {
    list: [
        { label: "Belarus", value: "BY" },
        { label: "China", value: "CN" },
        { label: "United States", value: "US" }
    ]
});
```

E o input fica simples:

```
<input id="myinput" />
```

Comment: Boa tb. +1 Podemos usar isso tb na solução final.

Comment: Eu, particularmente, sempre faço isso. Uma chamada armazena todos os valores e eu só faço a busca  nos valores já carregados. Mas faço usando o `JQuery autocomplete`, e não criando uma coisa nova.

Answer (score 1):

No html:

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="busca" onkeyUp="carregar()" placeholder="Pesquisar M&eacute;dico"/>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>


        </div>
```

No javascript:

```
  function xmlhttp(){
            // XMLHttpRequest para firefox e outros navegadores
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            // ActiveXObject para navegadores microsoft
            var versao = ['Microsoft.XMLHttp', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.5.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.4.0', 'Msxml2.XMLHttp.3.0','Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0'];
            for (var i = 0; i < versao.length; i++){
                try{
                    return new ActiveXObject(versao[i]);
                }catch(e){
                    alert("Seu navegador não possui recursos para o uso do AJAX!");
                }
            } // fecha for
            return null;
        } // fecha função xmlhttp

        //função para fazer a requisição da página que efetuará a consulta no DB
        function carregar(){
           a = document.getElementById('busca').value;
           ajax = xmlhttp();
           if (ajax){
               ajax.open('get','busca.php?nome='+a, true);
               ajax.onreadystatechange = trazconteudo;
               ajax.send(null);
           }
        }
        //função para incluir o conteúdo na pagina
        function trazconteudo(){
            if (ajax.readyState==4){
                if (ajax.status==200){
                    document.getElementById('searchlist').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
```

no PHP:

```
$nome = strtoupper($_GET['nome']);
require_once './controller/Pessoa_Controller.class.php';
require_once './beans/Pessoa.class.php';
require_once './servicos/PessoaListIterator.class.php';
$p = new Pessoa_Controller();
if($nome == ""){
    $nome = "%";
}else{
    $nome = "%".$nome."%";
}
$pessoaList_in = $p->lista($nome);
$pLista = new PessoaListIterator($pessoaList_in);
$pessoa =  new Pessoas();
while ($pLista->hasNextPessoas()){
    $pessoa = $pLista->getNextPessoas();
 ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
 <div  class="list-group">
        <A href="lista.php?codigo=<?php echo $pessoa->getId(); ?>&&nome=<?php echo $pessoa->getNome(); ?>" class="btn btn-default list-group-item" id="#<?php echo $pessoa->getId(); ?>" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="medico(<?php echo $pessoa->getId(); ?>);">
           <span><?php echo $pessoa->getNome(); ?></span> 
        </a>
  </div>    
</div>                                
<?php
}   
 ?>
```

Espero que dê uma ideia

Answer (score 1):

Teste esse exemplo HTML, para ser sincero não sei o limite de item que podem ser adicionados ao DATALIST, mas é uma questão de testes.
Ai a solução sem sobrecarregar o servidor e sem reinventar a roda.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste datalist</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<input name="idestados" list="listaestados" >         

<datalist id="listaestados">
    <select>
        <option value="12"> Acre</option>
        <option value="27"> Alagoas </option>
        <option value="16"> Amapá </option>
        <option value="13"> Amazonas </option>
        <option value="29"> Bahia </option>
        <option value="23"> Ceará </option>
        <option value="53"> Distrito Federal </option>
        <option value="32"> Espírito Santo </option>
        <option value="52"> Goiás </option>
        <option value="21"> Maranhão </option>
        <option value="51"> Mato Grosso </option>
        <option value="50"> Mato Grosso do Sul </option>
        <option value="31"> Minas Gerais </option>
        <option value="15"> Pará </option>
        <option value="25"> Paraíba </option>
        <option value="41"> Paraná </option>
        <option value="26"> Pernambuco </option>
        <option value="22"> Piauí </option>
        <option value="33"> Rio de Janeiro </option>
        <option value="24"> Rio Grande do Norte </option>
        <option value="43"> Rio Grande do Sul </option>
        <option value="11"> Rondônia </option>
        <option value="14"> Roraima </option>
        <option value="42"> Santa Catarina </option>
        <option value="35"> São Paulo </option>
        <option value="28"> Sergipe </option>
        <option value="17"> Tocantins </option>
    </select>
</datalist>        


</body>
```

Comment: Curti. Não conhecia essa tag datalist do html5 ainda. 
Nesse exemplo do W3Schools mostra digitando catando do datalist: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist
Provavelmente tb vai ser útil na solução final. +1

Answer (score 1):

Eu combino Angular Material com WebApi, porém utilizo asp.net mvc

https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/demo/autocomplete

Para pesquisar cidades e estados, você pode colocar um delay para atrasar a consulta e combinar o máximo de palavras e é muito ágil e fácil, não carrega tanto a consulta e o web api só retorna os resultados que deram match na consulta, então fica bem mais fácil trabalhar assim.